# AJAX Post to Different URL within Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, heroku

I am trying to use the Django S3Direct plugin to upload large files directly to my Amazon S3 bucket so as not to time out my Heroku dyno (see plugin link here: https://github.com/bradleyg/django-s3direct)

My HTML is setup like so (I've redacted parts of my form to make it more readable):

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-add-listing" action="" method="post" >
    ...
    <div class="s3direct" data-url="/s3direct/get_upload_params/s3direct/photos">
        <a class="link" target="_blank" href="" style="display: none;"></a>
        <span class="btn btn-file">
            <span class="fileupload-new">Select image</span>
            <span class="fileupload-exists">Change</span>
            <input type="hidden" value="" id="id_primary_image" name="primary_image" />
            <input type="file" class="fileinput" />
        </span>
        <a href="#remove" class="btn fileupload-exists" data-dismiss="fileupload">Remove</a>
        <div class="progress progress-striped active" style="margin-top:10px">
            <div class="bar"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

The associated AJAX looks something like this (s3direct.js):

```
var attach = function($fileInput, policy_url, el){
  $fileInput.fileupload({
    paramName: 'file',
    autoUpload: true,
    dataType: 'xml',
    add: function(e, data){
      $(el).attr('class', 's3direct progress-active')

      $.ajax({
        url: policy_url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: {type: data.files[0].type},
        success: function(fields) {
          data.url = fields.form_action
          delete fields.form_action
          data.formData = fields
          data.submit()
        }
      })
    },

    progress: function(e, data){
      var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10)
      $(el).find('.bar').css({width: progress + '%'})
    },

    error: function(e, data){
      alert('Oops, file upload failed, please try again')
      $(el).attr('class', 's3direct form-active')
    },

    done: function(e, data){
      var url = $(data.result).find('Location').text().replace(/%2F/g, '/')
      var file_name = url.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '')
      $(el).find('.link').attr('href', url).text(file_name)
      $(el).attr('class', 's3direct link-active')
      $(el).find('input[type=hidden]').val(url)
      $(el).find('.bar').css({width: '0%'})
    }
  })
}
```

Upon trying to upload, I encounter the following errors:

```
POST http://0.0.0.0:5000/listings/add/ 403 (FORBIDDEN) 
GET http://0.0.0.0:5000/accounts/signin/?next=/s3direct/get_upload_params/s3direct/photos 404 (NOT FOUND)
```

So what I'm gathering is that the Ajax is going to my form's URL (action="") rather than to the policy url (which was set in the JS). Then there is a GET request to some very weird version of the policy url.

I've been toying with this for a few hours and can't really figure out why it's resulting in this behavior. Would really appreciate some insight. Thank you.

Comment: AJAX can be inspected by *browser developer tools* in all major browsers, usually (always?) under "Network" tab. First step should be to make sure what AJAX actually does.

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question. I've already explained what the AJAX is doing, but I don't know why it is doing that and what can I do to fix it.

Comment: Did upi fix this issue? I have the same issue now